# Working with pairs of related columns (dplyr, tidyr, data.table)

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame of multiple pairs of estimates and variances for several model parameters each within one of a number of sections. Here's a function that generates the illustrative sample:

```
samplerats <- function(){
    set.seed(310366)
    d = data.frame(section=c(rep("S1",10),rep("S2",10),rep("S3",5)))
    nr = nrow(d)
    for(i in 1:5){
        d[[paste0("est_v",i)]] = rnorm(nr)
        d[[paste0("var_v",i)]] = runif(nr)
    }
    d
}
```

and here's the start of what you get:

```
> d=samplerats()
> head(d)
  section     est_v1    var_v1     est_v2     var_v2      est_v3    var_v3
1      S1  0.3893008 0.1620882 -1.1915391 0.15439565  0.62022284 0.5487519
2      S1  0.8221099 0.3280630  0.7729817 0.14810283 -1.11337584 0.9947342
3      S1  0.8023230 0.1862810 -1.5285389 0.85648574 -1.74666907 0.4267944
4      S1 -0.2252865 0.5660111 -0.4348341 0.53013027  0.01823185 0.1379821
5      S1 -0.9475335 0.7904085 -1.0882961 0.40567780  1.69607397 0.3450983
6      S1  0.4415259 0.2969032  0.9200723 0.08754107  0.57010457 0.7579002
[with another two variables and 25 rows in total]
```

The task is to compute the ratio the variance of the estimates for each parameter with the mean of the variance for each parameter, grouped by section.

So for example, for variable v1, crudely just to get the numbers out:

```
> d %>% group_by(section) %>% summarise(var(est_v1)/mean(var_v1))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  section var(est_v1)/mean(var_v1)
1      S1                0.5874458
2      S2                2.4449153
3      S3                2.8621725
```

That gives us the answer for `v1`, we just need to repeat for all the other variables. Note that the column names are `est_` or `var_` followed by a variable name which might be `alpha` or `g2` or some other alphanum.

Of course I have a horrendous solution:

```
ratit <- function(d){
    isVAR <- function(s){stringr::str_sub(s,1,4)=="var_"}

    spreads = reshape2::melt(d) %>% mutate(isVAR=isVAR(variable), Variable = str_replace(variable,"^.*_",""))
    vout = spreads %>% group_by(Variable, section, isVAR) %>% summarise(Z=if(isVAR(variable[1])){mean(value)}else{var(value)})
    ratios = vout %>% group_by(section, Variable) %>% summarise(Vratio = Z[1]/Z[2]) %>% dcast(section ~ Variable)
    ratios
}
```

which gives:

```
> ratit(d)
Using section as id variables
Using Vratio as value column: use value.var to override.
  section        v1       v2       v3        v4       v5
1      S1 0.5874458 3.504169 3.676488 1.1716684 1.742021
2      S2 2.4449153 1.177326 1.106337 1.0700636 3.263149
3      S3 2.8621725 2.216099 3.846062 0.7777452 2.122726
```

where you can see the first column is the same as the `v1`-only example earlier. But yuck.

If I can melt, cast, dplyr or otherwise tidyr it up into this format:

```
         est       var section  variable
1  0.3893008 0.1620882      S1        v1
2  0.8221099 0.3280630      S1        v1
3  0.8023230 0.1862810      S1        v1
4 -0.2252865 0.5660111      S1        v1
5 -0.9475335 0.7904085      S1        v1
6  0.4415259 0.2969032      S1        v1
```

then its trivial - `dd %>% group_by(section, variable) %>% summarise(rat=var(est)/mean(var)) %>% spread(variable, rat)`

But that step eludes me...

Neat solutions welcome, using anything including base R, dplyr, tidyr, data.table etc.

Comment: I'd argue that you don't have tidy data, so it's going to be hard to use dplyr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one solution with `base R` using `mapply`

```
est <- d[grep('^est|section', colnames(d))]
var1 <- d[grep('^var|section', colnames(d))]
lstest <- split(est[-1], est$section)
lstvar <- split(var1[-1], var1$section)

res <- t(mapply(function(x,y) mapply(function(.x, .y) 
          var(.x)/mean(.y), x, y), lstest, lstvar))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 est1 <- est %>% 
          group_by(section) %>%
          summarise_each(funs(var)) %>% 
          data.frame()

 var2 <- var1 %>%
            group_by(section) %>% 
            summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% 
             data.frame()

 est1[-1]/var2[-1]
```

#### Benchmarks

**data**

```
samplerats <- function(){
  set.seed(310366)
  d <- data.frame(section=sample(paste0("S", 1:20), 
                                    1e5, replace=TRUE))
  nr <- nrow(d)
  for(i in 1:20){
   d[[paste0('est_v', i)]] <- rnorm(nr)
   d[[paste0('var_v', i)]] <- runif(nr)
   }
  d
}
d <- samplerats()
```

**Functions**

```
akrun <- function(){
     est1 <- d %>% 
               group_by(section) %>%
               summarise_each(funs(var), starts_with('est')) 
     var1 <- d %>%
               group_by(section) %>% 
               summarise_each(funs(mean), starts_with('var') )
      cbind(unique(est1[1]), est1[-1]/var1[-1])
   }

  #Assuming that the `reshaped` dataset from @Josh O'Brien's method 
  #is further processed using `spread` from `tidyr`

  josh <- function(){
     dd <- reshape(d, varying = 2:ncol(d), direction = 'long', 
             sep="_", timevar="variable")
     dd %>%
        group_by(section, variable) %>%
        summarise(rat=var(est)/mean(var)) %>%
        spread(variable, rat)
      }

   #Using `data.table` for @Henriks' method as the output from
   # `merged.stack is `data.table`

  henrik <- function(){
      dS <- merged.stack(data = getanID(d, "section"), 
         var.stubs = c("est", "var"), sep = "_")
       dcast.data.table(dS[ , list(rat=var(est)/mean(var)),
        .(section, .time_1)], section~.time_1, value.var='rat')
        }    

  DMC <- function(){       
           d %>%
           gather(key, value, -section) %>%
           separate(key, into = c("type", "var")) %>%
           group_by(section, var) %>%
           summarise(result = var(value[type == "est"]) / mean(value[type == "var"]))%>%
           spread(var, result) 
          }
```

**benchmarks**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun(), josh(), henrik(), DMC(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#akrun()   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000    20
# josh() 323.57129 335.51929 315.05115 312.02953 293.18614 308.30833    20
#henrik() 30.02737  33.95731  32.15254  34.72281  29.55944  35.26825    20
#DMC()   204.66445 211.82019 207.47286 201.33015 207.10875 231.24048    20
# cld
# a   
# d
# b  
# c
```

@alexis_laz's solution came a bit late.  Here is the `system.time`

```
 system.time({cbind(levels(d$section), 
    aggregate(. ~ section, d[c(1, grep("^est_", names(d)))], var)[-1] / 
   aggregate(. ~ section, d[c(1, grep("^var_", names(d)))], mean)[-1])}
 )
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.228   0.002   2.229 
system.time(akrun())
#   user  system elapsed 
# 0.034   0.000   0.035
```

Comment: Benchmarked on my original, smaller, dataset DMC and akrun are about equal first, henrik takes about 3x as long. Even my original crufty mess isn't that slow. So the scaling with data size is interesting. I had thought about doing two pipelines as in the akrun function, but my mental image is that setting up a pipeline is expensive - it clearly isnt, the time is dominated by what the pipeline is doing.

Comment: Have accepted this one (in its dplyr variant) since it does the job in one step, is quick, compact, readable, and illustrates that sometimes trying to do everything in one pipeline is not a good idea.

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick:

```
dd <- reshape(d, varying = 2:11, direction = 'long', sep="_", timevar="variable")

head(dd)
#      section variable        est       var id
# 1.v1      S1       v1  0.3893008 0.1620882  1
# 2.v1      S1       v1  0.8221099 0.3280630  2
# 3.v1      S1       v1  0.8023230 0.1862810  3
# 4.v1      S1       v1 -0.2252865 0.5660111  4
# 5.v1      S1       v1 -0.9475335 0.7904085  5
# 6.v1      S1       v1  0.4415259 0.2969032  6
```

Answer (score 7):

An "etc" solution:

```
library(splitstackshape)
Reshape(data = d, id.vars = "section", var.stubs = c("est", "var"), sep = "_")
#      section .id time        est        var
#   1:      S1   1    1  0.3893008 0.16208821
#   2:      S1   2    1  0.8221099 0.32806300
#   3:      S1   3    1  0.8023230 0.18628100
#   4:      S1   4    1 -0.2252865 0.56601106
#   5:      S1   5    1 -0.9475335 0.79040846
# ---                                       
# 121:      S3   1    5  0.4823552 0.57649912
# 122:      S3   2    5  0.6624314 0.27159239
# 123:      S3   3    5 -0.7515308 0.09077159
# 124:      S3   4    5 -0.4426505 0.81389532
# 125:      S3   5    5  1.3881995 0.01433167

# or
merged.stack(data = getanID(d, "section"), var.stubs = c("est", "var"), sep = "_")
#      section .id .time_1         est        var
#   1:      S1   1      v1  0.38930083 0.16208821
#   2:      S1   1      v2 -1.19153913 0.15439565
#   3:      S1   1      v3  0.62022284 0.54875189
#   4:      S1   1      v4  0.07671314 0.71301067
#   5:      S1   1      v5  0.53539985 0.86674969
# ---                                           
# 121:      S3   5      v1  0.87184287 0.63119596
# 122:      S3   5      v2  1.26976583 0.50432276
# 123:      S3   5      v3  0.02390527 0.55614582
# 124:      S3   5      v4  0.15269326 0.93073954
# 125:      S3   5      v5  1.38819949 0.01433167
```

Comment: @Spacedman, FYI, just realized there was an even simpler `splitstackshape` function: `Reshape` - added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This pipeline with `dplyr` skips the intermediate table.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  gather(key, value, est_v1:var_v5) %>%
  separate(key, into = c("type", "var")) %>%
  group_by(section, var) %>%
  summarise(
    result = var(value[type == "est"]) / mean(value[type == "var"])
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another try:

```
cbind(levels(d$section), 
      aggregate(. ~ section, d[c(1, grep("^est_", names(d)))], var)[-1] / 
      aggregate(. ~ section, d[c(1, grep("^var_", names(d)))], mean)[-1])
#  levels(d$section)    est_v1   est_v2   est_v3    est_v4   est_v5
#1                S1 0.5874458 3.504169 3.676488 1.1716684 1.742021
#2                S2 2.4449153 1.177326 1.106337 1.0700636 3.263149
#3                S3 2.8621725 2.216099 3.846062 0.7777452 2.122726
```